# Google Spreadsheet LOOKUP with dynamical search result of VLOOKUP

Tags: spreadsheet, gs-vlookup

please have a look at my spreadsheet mini example screenshot for demonstration:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ab3l3xdeb

I have created a price matrix for price calculation. In the first row you will find the search range. This is the buying price (EK). B1 means that the buying price is > 0, B2 means the buying price is > 10, ....
In the next rows (one row for each brand) you will find the multiplicator in percent we will add to the buying price base on the seach range.

Example (works with row1 as search range and row2 as search result):

A7: This is the brand. That means we have to work with row 2. (this is static yet and my problem)
B7: This is the buying price. It is 50
D7: Base on the brand and the buying price I look in the matrix and got the value 20
C7: This will be the final price as we increase the buying price for 20%

This is my calculation:

```
=B7*((LOOKUP(B7, B1:F1, B2:F2)+100)/100)
```

I will need "B2:F2" for Brand 1, "B3:F3" for Brand 2, ....

How can I including the Cell A7 in my calculation, that it automatically use the search result of the right row? I thougt of something with VLOOKUP. But this seems not to work.

I have no more idea.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In Cell C7, you could use the following formula to allow you to do a horizontal and vertical lookup at once:

```
=$B$7*((INDEX($B$2:$F$3,MATCH($A$7,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH($B$7,$B$1:$F$1,0))+100)/100)
```

This will return what you are looking for, meaning that you can change the Brand and EK in cells A7 and B7 and your lookup will still work.